# How to find the day of the week `tm_wday` from a given date?

Tags: c++, c, time, dayofweek

To find the day (number) for a given date, I wrote below code using `<ctime>`:

```
tm time {ANY_SECOND, ANY_MINUTE, ANY_HOUR, 21, 7, 2015 - 1900};
mktime(&time); //                          today's date                     
PRINT(time.tm_wday);  // prints 5 instead of 2 for Tuesday
```

According to the documentation, `tm_wday` can hold value among `[0-6]`, where 0 is Sunday. Hence for Tuesday (today), it should print 2; but it [prints 5](http://ideone.com/RXb5WB).
Actually `tm_wday` gives consistent results, but with a difference of 3 days.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Choose a language. C or C++ and stick to it. Do not change your code after getting an answer. It usually makes the answer invalid.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I don't see a need for sticking to only 1 of them. `<time.h>` and `<ctime>` are available in C and C++ respectively. Having both the tags on gives better visibility. The code is unchanged, just `std::` is removed from the code, to avoid someone untagging from C. That makes no difference.

Comment: your code is in `C`. Why tag `c++` then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got the month wrong, `tm_mon` is the offset since January, so July is 6. From the manpage:

> tm_mon The number of months since January, in the range 0 to 11.

This outputs `2`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    struct tm time;
    memset(&time, 0, sizeof(time));

    time.tm_mday = 21;
    time.tm_mon = 6;
    time.tm_year = 2015-1900;

    mktime(&time);

    printf("%d\n", time.tm_wday);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that you should initialize the other fields to 0 with `memset(3)` or similar.

Comment: My bad. I never cared on checking the month :-). With brace initializer, I believe the rest of the fields will be initialized to 0 automatically. Hence `memset()` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting invalid output is that you are using the wrong month.  tm_mon starts at 0 and not 1.  you can see tghis by using this code:

```
tm time {50, 50, 12, 21, 7, 2015 - 1900};
time_t epoch = mktime(&time);
printf("%s", asctime(gmtime(&epoch)));
```

Output:

```
Fri Aug 21 12:50:50 2015
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/240ad49ef29c9d61)